# How do I disable the new chrome browser bluetooth api?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to disable the [Chrome BlueTooth API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web)?

I understand that the apps will have to get my permission, but I would rather not be bothered. This is similar to pop-ups and new windows and location permission requests - there should be a way to say "NO" once and for all.

Comment: Since this is a question about using Google Chrome, and not about using a specific web app, it is off topic for [webapps.se].

Comment: It's a general question about all Web Apps that want to use Bluetooth - how to disable them. That said - where would you recommend that I ask this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable it with a setting or flag.

If it is very important to you (and you have Windows Pro) you can set block the API via the [Chrome GPO](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates) policies.

Here is the reference to the specific policy: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultWebBluetoothGuardSetting